# MySQL LOAD DATA LOCAL csv and create table and fields off first row of csv

Tags: mysql, csv

Is it possible have a query that will do the following...

- Load Data Local for a CSV file
- Create a table
- Create the fields based off the first row of the csv
- Insert the data from the csv into this new table

this is what I have right now:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\CaliberMap.csv'
INTO TABLE sefeed_calibermap
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
```

Comment: I don't think so. `LOAD DATA` can only load into an existing table, and the fields have to be there already.

Comment: How is it supposed to know what the correct datatypes and indexes are?

Comment: I figured this was maybe possible, cause in phpmyadmin I can upload a CSV and it creates a table anyways with an option to have the first row of the csv with the fields. I have 60 csv to import

Comment: That's phpMyAdmin figuring it out in its import command, not MySQL.

Comment: I cant run this import command manually

Comment: I know, it's a part of phpMyAdmin, it doesn't exist on its own.